How to install "aafire" in Docker on Ubuntu base image?
How can i load "aafire" in docker images in Ubuntu operating system?
I am trying to run the aafire application inside a Docker container based on the Ubuntu operating system. However, the package aafire does not appear to be available in the Ubuntu repository.
I attempted the following in my Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y aafire

But I received this error:

Unable to locate package aafire

What I’ve tried:
Changing the base image to ubuntu:16.04 and ubuntu:18.04, but the package is still not found.
Looking for an alternative repository or PPA for aafire, but couldn't find any.

The aafire program is in libaa-bin package, so change the Dockerfile like below:
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaa-bin

it should works.
